# cmd module: capture Ctrl+C

Tags: python, cmd, terminal, signals

I am using Python's default [cmd module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmd.html) to create a command-line-based app.

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.cmdloop) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (which signals EOF to the command line) can be captured by implementing a function called `do_EOF`, which works pretty well.

However, is there a way to capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as well? I want to execute a specific function (which saves all unsaved changes) before terminating the Python-script, which is the main motivation for doing this.

Currently, I capture `KeyboardInterrupts` using a `try-except-block` like the following:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        MyCmd().cmdloop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\n')
```

I tried to extend this into:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app = MyCmd().cmdloop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        app.execute_before_quit()
        print('\n')
```

Which leads to the following `NameError`:

```
name 'app' is not defined
```

How can I capture <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

I think [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) could somehow do the trick, but I am not sure...

---

Remark: The script needs to be running on both Unix- and Windows-based systems.

Comment: Have you considered using `atexit` instead?  https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl C activates system exit which is like an exception, I'm pretty sure you can catch it with try and except. Note: to catch SystemExit you must specify it in the except explicitly.